# can someone help me make this code smaller?

Tags: linux, bash

I need to upload this code, but the code is too large and confusing, can someone possibly help me to summarize this code or make it smaller? Its only the input part which's kinda confusing.

```
input(){
while read line;
do
for name in $line;
do
if [ "$name" == "`cat /etc/passwd | cut -f1 -d: | grep  "^$name"`" ]
then
#echo $name----------
        if [[ $s -eq 0 && $l -eq 0 && $i -eq 0 && $I -eq 0 && $u -eq 0 ]]; then
      standard
fi
if [ $s -eq 1 ]
then
        keepSudoUser
fi
if [ $l -eq 1 ]
then
        interactiveShell
fi
if [ $i -eq 1 ]
then
        userUnder1000
fi
if [ $I -eq 1 ]
then
        userOver1000
fi
if [ $u -eq 1 ]
then
        excludeUser
fi
fi
NO=0
done
done
}
input
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) ? It probably is better for such a task! Of course, **you need to read documentation** of both `gawk` and of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Answer (score 2):

This is more compact:

```sh
input() {
    while read -ra names; do
        for name in "${names[@]}"; do
            if grep -q "^${name}:" /etc/passwd; then
                [[ "$s$l$i$I$u" == "00000" ]] && standard
                (( s == 1 )) && keepSudoUser
                (( l == 1 )) && interactiveShell
                (( i == 1 )) && userUnder1000
                (( I == 1 )) && userOver1000
                (( u == 1 )) && excludeUser
            fi
            NO=0
        done
    done
}

input
```

A more strict translation would be

```sh
((s == 0 && l == 0 && i == 0 && I == 0 && u == 0)) && standard
# or
(( !(s || l || i || I || u) )) && standard
```